# Errrno 32 Pipe error, escpos python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, escpos

I need to test an Epson POS printer, TM-U220PD.
I have it connected by a Parallel converter to my laptop.
It's completely installed, but when I test it with python escpos shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/escpos/escpos.py", line 437, in text
    self._raw(txt.encode())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/escpos/printer.py", line 85, in _raw
    self.device.write(self.out_ep, msg, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/core.py", line 948, in write
    self.__get_timeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 824, in bulk_write
    timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 920, in __write
    _check(retval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 32] Pipe error
```

This is the code used to test:

```
>>> from escpos.printer import Usb
>>> p = Usb(0x067b, 0x2305)
>>> p.open()
>>> p.text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a USB-to-Parallel-converter should be mounted by your system into the filesystem (I assume you are on a *nix judging from your trace).
Usually this is something like `/dev/usb/lp0`.

For first debugging you can try to just writing to this "file":

```
echo "Test\n" > /dev/usb/lp0
```

If this works you should be able to successfully print with:

```
from escpos.printer import File
p = File(devfile='/dev/usb/lp0')
p.text("some text\n")
```